# Why axis2 generated proxy does not have any ServiceLocator class

Tags: java, apache-axis

I am new to Web Services. I have to use the crm web services to perform some task from my java application. I am using Eclipse Galileo on Tomcat Application server. I have downloaded the WSDL from CRM web site and generated the Proxies through Axis2 WSDL2Java command. 
Now I don't know how to use Axis2 generated proxy classes in my java app as the class structure is different from the Axis1.X generated classes. How to set up the connections(Endpoint and ports) is the point where I got stuck.
Please Help me out.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a constructor that will take a string representing the endpoint on whatever generated class that extends `org.apache.axis2.client.Stub`